# $BASH_VERSION reports old version of bash on macOS, is this a problem that should be fixed?

Tags: bash, macos

I have homebrew's bash package installed. When I open a new shell:

`bash --version` gives `GNU bash, version 5.0.7(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0)`

`which bash` gives `/usr/local/bin/bash` as expected.

But:

`echo $BASH_VERSION` yields `3.2.57(1)-release`

I'm wondering if this is something I should address for scripts that might use this environment variable.

Answer (score 11):

It means that the shell you're in is Bash 3.2, but `bash` points to Bash 5.0. Try `bash` and then, in the new shell, `echo $BASH_VERSION` – I guess it'll be 5.0. To change your login shell, add `/usr/local/bin/bash` to `/etc/shells` and change the default shell with

```
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash
sudo chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash
```

After logging out and in again, `$BASH_VERSION` should be updated.

As for shebang lines, I recommend

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

as it's portable and will use the first Bash in your `$PATH`.

Answer (score 8):

The source of my problem was a terminal app preference setting. The "Command (complete path)" was set to `/bin/bash`. After setting it to "Default login shell", `echo $BASH_VERSION` reported the version I expected. The other problem is I stupidly ran the `bash --version` command in iTerm2, not terminal. So it gave a different response than what terminal would have.

Comment: `bash --version` doesn't _ever_ report the version of bash you're actually running; it only reports what version the interpreter that comes first in `PATH` would be. So running `bash --version` in Terminal wouldn't necessarily have made any difference.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you man, this was driving me nuts, but can you elaborate what do you mean exactly? there's only one path to bash in my path which is v 5.. no mention to v 3 whatsoever!

Comment: @kapreski, v3 exists in `/bin` on MacOS unavoidably -- it's put there by Apple and you can't uninstall it even with root without disabling integrity protection. And `/bin` _has_ to be listed in your PATH environment variable somewhere, or a lot of tools don't work. So it's just a question of whether `/bin` is before or after the place where you have a newer release installed that determines what `bash --version` outputs. Which of those directories is first in PATH is a _completely different_ question from which version of bash you're actively using, which is what `echo "$BASH_VERSION"` shows.

Comment: @kapreski, see `declare -p PATH` or `echo "$PATH"` to see the variable I'm talking about when I say `PATH`; I'm using it to refer to the specific environment variable by that name, not as a generic term (I'd leave it uncapitalized and not code-quoted if I meant to use the word "path" as regular English prose).

Comment: @Charles Duffy I see, the `$PATH` variable does indeed point to multiple` /bin` directories, with one of them containing the older bash version 3, I suppose. By adding the location of the new bash at the beginning of my `$PATH` I managed to make the `bash -v` command report the new bash version 5.

Just a quick note for anyone reading this: make sure you don't directly specify the bash executable in your `$PATH` variable, like don't do this `some_directory/bin/bash`. Instead, point to the directory where your bash resides, like this `some_directory/bin/` <-- (bash resides in there).

Answer (score 2):

Your login shell (see `echo $SHELL`) is probably `/bin/bash` and that is the one setting  `$BASH_VERSION`. If you need to use a specific version in scripts, use the full path in the `#!` line.

Comment: Yes, I realize that now. I had assumed homebrew would symlink. I've read symlinking is not possible without overriding mac's security measures. What I don't get, though, is my default shell is set to /usr/local/bin/bash. So why wouldn't that version of bash get reported?

Comment: OK, the issue was the terminal app's preferences setting. The "Command (complete path)" was set to `/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check that the terminal you are using is using the default login shell and not a custom one.

Answer (score 0):

0) First install bash with brew:

```
brew install bash
```

1) Edit the file "/etc/shells" (Where brew installs bash) to include the line:

```
/usr/local/bin/bash
```

2) On your terminal change the shell:

```
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash
```

3) By default osx's bash does not read `.bashrc` but `.bash_profile`, so do the following:

```
echo "if [ -s ~/.bashrc ]; then source ~/.bashrc; fi" > .bash_profile`
```